# How to display coordinates on map received from GCM?

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinates, google-cloud-messaging

I developed an app in which i am receiving latitude and longitude through GCM from my php server, so what i want is that if my Map Activity is already opened display these coordinates on map else generate notification. Please guide me how to do this.

This is my GcmIntentService

```
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService{
    Context context;
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    public static final String TAG = "GCM Demo";

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }



    @Override
        protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            String msg = intent.getStringExtra("message");
            GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

             if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

                 if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                            MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                        sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
                    } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                            MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                        sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                                extras.toString());
                    // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
                    } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                            MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                        // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                                    + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(500);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            }
                        }
                        Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                        // Post notification of received message.
                        //sendNotification("Received: " + extras.toString());
                        sendNotification(msg);
                        Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
                    }
                }
             GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
        }
        private void sendNotification(String msg) {
            mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                    this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

            Log.i(TAG, msg);

            Intent myintent = new Intent(this, Map.class);
            myintent.putExtra("message", msg);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                    myintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                    new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
            .bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
        }




}
```

This is how i am extracting latitude and longitude from message received from GCM

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("message");
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(message);
            String lat = json.getString("lati");
            String lon = json.getString("longi");

            if ( map != null ) {

                Double l1,l2;



                l1 = Double.parseDouble(lat);
                l2 = Double.parseDouble(lon);


                LatLng newLatLong = new LatLng(l1, l2);
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(newLatLong)
                              .title("Hello"));

            }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: When `GCM` send Message to your device get `Latitude` and `Longitude` from that Message and generate one `Notification` using `Notification.Builder` and set `PendingIntent` as your `MainActicity` and send this `Latitude` and `Longitude` as `Bundle` in your `MainActicity` and get this `Bundle` in your `MainActivity` and extract  `Latitude` and `Longitude`and add as `Marker` in your Map.

Comment: @SimplePlan what i want is that when these coordinates arrive on my device so if my map activity already open so these coordinates appear on map otherwise display notification. Kindly help me how to do this.

Comment: One way you can achieve this. First you check whether your activity on Background or Foreground. Now, if your activity in Background then generate a notification using `Notification.Builder`. and if your activity in Foreground then Receive the Latitude and Longitude from `GCM` Message and store this Latitude and Longitude in some class and then plot it as a Location in your Map.

Comment: @SimplePlan please can you guide me how to do this as i am new into android development.